# Ionic 3 get Image path from template which user clicks on

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the image url(local) from the template into my ts file. The images load dynamically from a json file. So when a user clicks on a specific image, I need to get the image path so that I can base64 encode it. I am successfully displaying the images in my template. It's just how to get the path back into my ts based on the users click which is giving me a problem.

My code is as follows

html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let i of festivalData" (click)="twitterShare(i)">
    <img src={{i.festivalImage}}>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        {{i.festivalName}}
      </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        {{i.festivalDescription}}
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

ts:

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {

      this.http.get('assets/data.json').subscribe(data => {
        this.festivalData = data;
      });

  } 

  twitterShare(index){
    this.socialSharing.shareViaTwitter("message", "");
  }
```

If it was a normal input box, I know I could use a [(ngModel)] but it does not seem to work here

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update :

```
twitterShare(index){
    this.socialSharing.shareViaTwitter("message", "");
    console.log(index.festivalImage);
  }
```

`index.festivalImage` will contain the path of image clicked.

---

You can load it the similar way you are loading json from assests.

```
./assets/myImage.png
```

This is a super cool hack to make base64 stream of local file.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
    xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/local/image/file", true); 
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(this.response);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
               var res = event.target.result;
               console.log(res)
            }
            var file = this.response;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    };
    xhr.send()
```

This will have the base64 string....

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
                   var res = event.target.result;
                   console.log(res)
                }
```

Comment: Thanks but the base64 is not the problem, it's getting the image path back from the template in angular based on the users click which is

Comment: Updated answer...check if this helps.

Comment: yes this works, thanks so much, much appreciated. marked as correct answer